# Accessing properties of object using JXA

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to access the properties of an object in an app called Papers3 using JXA. I'm new to JXA and this is proving challenging, especially because of the lack of documentation.

Here is a shot of the dictionary for the object I'm trying to look at

[image]

I'm trying to get the IDs for the currently displayed windows in the app.

My attempt at this is:

```
var Papers = Application('Papers');
Papers.includeStandardAdditions = true
Papers.libraryWindow.displayedPublications()
```

Running it throws an error and the output is:

`Error on line 4: TypeError: Papers.libraryWindow.displayedPublications is not a function. (In 'Papers.libraryWindow.displayedPublications()', 'Papers.libraryWindow.displayedPublications' is undefined)`

`Error -2700: Script error.`

Also, if I call just `Papers.libraryWindow`

The result is:

```
  [function anonymous] {
  "name":"", 
  "prototype":{"constructor":[function anonymous]}
}
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little detail, I think. `libraryWindow` needs to be plural and it's necessary to specify which one. You can use several forms:

- *Index form* eg. `libraryWindows[0]`
- *ByName* eg. `libraryWindows.byName('Papers')`

  So, to access the first library window, you use: `libraryWindows[0]`.

Try this:

```
(() => {
    'use strict'

    const app = Application('Papers');
    const oWin = app.libraryWindows[0]

    return oWin.displayedPublications()
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, JXA is broken obfuscated moribund junk and AS not much better off either, but the key thing to understand here is that Apple event IPC is **not** OOP, it is *RPC + simple first-class relational queries*. Despite the syntactic sugar, its closest relative is actually SQL database programming, not browser DOM manipulation, so once you get your head around that it’ll [hopefully] start to make a bit more sense.

An “AppleScriptable” application presents its data as a heavily abstracted relational graph—an “Apple Event Object Model”—where each node is related to other nodes by one-to-one and/or one-to-many relationships. There’s no such thing as “classes” or “objects” in the OO sense; it’s just the jargon that got attached for documentation purposes. Thus what an application’s dictionary calls a “property” is either a simple attribute containing a primitive value (number, string, list, etc; e.g. the `name` property of a Finder `file`) or a one-to-one relationship (e.g. the `current track` property of iTunes’ `application`), and what it calls “elements” is a one-to-many relationship (in your case, the `libraryWindows` elements of Papers’ `application` object).

For example, `Papers.libraryWindows.displayedPublications.get()` *should* return a list of the displayed publications of every library window in Papers (though whether that actually works in practice depends on how well implemented an app’s AEOM is, not to mention JXA’s own implementation issues); or you can use various reference forms (by-index, by-name, etc; though several are broken/unsupported in JXA) to narrow your query to, say, just the first library window, e.g. `Papers.libraryWindows[0].displayedPublications.get()`.

You might get some insight from browsing the NodeAutomation documentation, which includes a [rough overview of AEOM](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/nodeautomation/src/df5b08ed0659eac60a1ab60929d5c3fb23172e8f/doc-src/02-overview.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and how to assemble queries which you then send to it via commands (remote procedure calls) to resolve and process as it sees fit. JXA syntax isn’t as pretty, and various operations that work perfectly in AS barf in JXA, but it’ll give you a rough idea.

That said, I strongly recommend sticking to AppleScript. The language is a mess, but at least it has *some* documentation and user community to help you find your way around it (even if they don’t deeply understand it either).

Answer (score 1):

For Papers 3 specific JXA examples, see:
[mac-scripting - Automation scripts for macOS](https://github.com/extracts/mac-scripting)

For more general info, see:
[JXA Resources](https://apple-dev.groups.io/g/jxa/wiki/JXA-Resources)